# @Published property wrapper and its wrappedValue

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When you define your own property wrapper you must specify a *non-static property named 'wrappedValue'*. For example:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct MyPropertyWrapper<Value> {
    var value: Value
}
```

with the code above the compiler complains that:

> Property wrapper type 'MyPropertyWrapper' does not contain a
>   non-static property named 'wrappedValue'

So, you can fix the error simply doing:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct MyPropertyWrapper<Value> {
    var value: Value

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            value
        }
        set {
            value = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Just to make some examples this is true for `@State`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@propertyWrapper public struct State<Value> : DynamicProperty {

    /// The current state value.
    public var wrappedValue: Value { get nonmutating set }
}
```

the same for `@Binding`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@propertyWrapper @dynamicMemberLookup public struct Binding<Value> {

    /// The value referenced by the binding. Assignments to the value
    /// will be immediately visible on reading (assuming the binding
    /// represents a mutable location), but the view changes they cause
    /// may be processed asynchronously to the assignment.
    public var wrappedValue: Value { get nonmutating set }
}
```

and so forth. But the `@Published` property wrapper doesn't have a wrapped value:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
@propertyWrapper public struct Published<Value> {

    /// Initialize the storage of the Published property as well as the corresponding `Publisher`.
    public init(initialValue: Value)

    /// A publisher for properties marked with the `@Published` attribute.
    public struct Publisher : Publisher {

        /// The kind of values published by this publisher.
        public typealias Output = Value

        /// The kind of errors this publisher might publish.
        ///
        /// Use `Never` if this `Publisher` does not publish errors.
        public typealias Failure = Never

        /// This function is called to attach the specified `Subscriber` to this `Publisher` by `subscribe(_:)`
        ///
        /// - SeeAlso: `subscribe(_:)`
        /// - Parameters:
        ///     - subscriber: The subscriber to attach to this `Publisher`.
        ///                   once attached it can begin to receive values.
        public func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where Value == S.Input, S : Subscriber, S.Failure == Published<Value>.Publisher.Failure
    }

    /// The property that can be accessed with the `$` syntax and allows access to the `Publisher`
    public var projectedValue: Published<Value>.Publisher { mutating get }
}
```

I'm missing something for sure here, since the compiler won't let you create a property wrapper without the `wrappedValue`. What's the difference in this case respect to the other property wrappers?

Comment: Have you looked at all the extensions on `Published`?

Comment: It can't be on an extension because an extension can't define a stored property

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you have shown isn't the *actual implementation* of `@Published` - It is merely the publicly visible interface.  If you paste that code into Xcode you will get the same error regarding `wrappedValue` among others;  That code doesn't compile.

`wrappedValue` has an access level of `internal` - So we can assume that the actual implementation of `@Published` declares something like `internal var wrappedValue:Value`.  This satisfies the property wrapper requirement but means that `wrappedValue` is not visible outside of its framework.

Comment: Thank you. That must be the reason. I missed the fact the wrappedValue has the scope _internal_.

Comment: I've tried to add an "internal" wrappedValue for my "public" property wrapper, and the compiler still does not allow the code to compile. The error is the following:

"Internal property 'wrappedValue' cannot have more restrictive access than its enclosing property wrapper type 'SomeWrapper' (which is public)"